# How to have both visible and template binding for Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, javascript-framework, knockout-templating

What is the right way to have different bindings on the same target in Knockout.

These didn't seem to work:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'voucher-template', foreach: voucher }" data-bind="visible: showVoucher"></div>
```

or

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'voucher-template', foreach: voucher }, visible: showVoucher"></div>
```

Full Test code:

```
<script>

        function VoucherViewModel() {
            this.voucher = [
            {
                VoucherNumber: "100000",
                VoucherImage: "someurl",
                VoucherExpiry: "20/3/12",
                VoucherRedeemed: true,
                VoucherDesc: "ddwqdwqdwqd",
                VoucherPuchaseDate: "20/12/11",
                VoucherPrice: "50"
            }, 
            {
                VoucherNumber: "200000",
                VoucherImage: "someurl",
                VoucherExpiry: "20/3/12",
                VoucherRedeemed: true,
                VoucherDesc: "ddwqdwqdwqd",
                VoucherPuchaseDate: "20/12/11",
                VoucherPrice: "50"
            }]
        };

        var viewModel = {
            showVoucher: ko.observable(true)
        };

        $(function () {

            //VIEWMODEL
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            //TEMPLATES
            ko.applyBindings(new VoucherViewModel());

        });
    </script>






<div data-bind="template: { name: 'voucher-template', foreach: voucher }, visible: showVoucher"></div>        
<script type="text/html" id="voucher-template">
<h3 data-bind="text: VoucherNumber"></h3>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the double ko.applyBindings is causing an issue.

This worked:

```
$(function () {

            var viewModel = {
                showVoucher: ko.observable(true),
                voucher: ko.observableArray([
                    {
                        VoucherNumber: "100000",
                        VoucherImage: "someurl",
                        VoucherExpiry: "20/3/12",
                        VoucherRedeemed: true,
                        VoucherDesc: "ddwqdwqdwqd",
                        VoucherPuchaseDate: "20/12/11",
                        VoucherPrice: "50"
                    },
                    {
                        VoucherNumber: "200000",
                        VoucherImage: "someurl",
                        VoucherExpiry: "20/3/12",
                        VoucherRedeemed: true,
                        VoucherDesc: "ddwqdwqdwqd",
                        VoucherPuchaseDate: "20/12/11",
                        VoucherPrice: "50"
                    }
                ])
            };

            //VIEWMODEL
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    


        });
```

If there is a better way to write this, please let me know.

**Edited version below, also trying out mapping:**

```
<script>

        function getVoucherData() {
            //some ajax call;

            return data = { "voucher" : [{
                VoucherTitle: "Offer title 1",
                VoucherNumber: "100000",
                VoucherImage: "someurl",
                VoucherExpiry: "20/3/12",
                VoucherRedeemed: true,
                VoucherDesc: "ddwqdwqdwqd",
                VoucherPuchaseDate: "20/12/11",
                VoucherPrice: "50"
            },
            {
                VoucherTitle: "Offer title 2",
                VoucherNumber: "200000",
                VoucherImage: "someurl",
                VoucherExpiry: "20/3/12",
                VoucherRedeemed: true,
                VoucherDesc: "ddwqdwqdwqd",
                VoucherPuchaseDate: "20/12/11",
                VoucherPrice: "50"
            }]
            };
        }

        function initViewModel() {
            var viewModel = {};

           // PAGE SETUP
           viewModel.showVoucher = ko.observable(true);
           viewModel.showMyAccount = ko.observable(false);

           // GET VOUCHER
           var voucherData = getVoucherData();
           voucherData.voucher.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left.VoucherNumber > right.VoucherNumber
           });
           viewModel.voucher = ko.mapping.fromJS(voucherData.voucher);

           // START
           ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
       }

       $(function () {
           initViewModel();        
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Instead of using `fromJS` I would recommend just instantiating a new variable as an emtpy observableArray and go ahead and do all the bindings. Then after you get your data from the ajax call, you set the view model field like this: viewModel.voucher(voucherData.voucher)

Comment: I ended up not using knockout. There weren't features I needed that can't be implemented using just jQuery. I also eventually used my own html template in markup (with jQuery clone function.) Not using  templates that were enclosed in script tags with data binding everywhere turned out to be a relief (much easier to read). It's nice to seperate script and binding controls outside the html.

Answer (score 0):

You specify multiple bindings in Knockout by separating them with a comma (it is essentially a JavaScript object literal) in the same `data-bind` attribute.  So, you will want to do:

```
data-bind="bindingOne: valueOne, bindingTwo: { valueTwo: 'two' }, bindingThree: valueThree"
```

Comment: look like what I'm doing in the 2nd code example? 1st binding is template and 2nd binding delimited by coma is visible.

Comment: error message is: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: voucher is not defined; Bindings value: template: { name: 'voucher-template', foreach: voucher }, visible: showVoucher

Comment: Yes, you generally want to call `ko.applyBindings` only one time.  You should build your view model such that it contains all of the elements that you want to bind against.  The way that you wrote it in your sample is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would recommend and as far as I understand it is best practise.  This is because you set a structure on the viewModel within the function rather than appending later which is easier to read.

```
$(function () {
    function MyViewModel() {
        // data
        this.showVoucher = ko.observable(true);
        this.showMyAccount = ko.observable(false);
        this.voucher = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    window.activeViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(window.activeViewModel);

    // GET VOUCHERS
    var voucherData = getVoucherData();
    window.activeViewModel.voucher(voucherData.voucher)
});
```